# Find the derivative of: $\left(\left(\left(x^2 + x\right)^3 + x^4\right)+ x\right)^5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hi this question derivative is giving me some difficulty, I understand how to use the chain rule but I feel you have to use more than two functions which I'm struggling with, here the question:

Find the derivative of:

$$\left(\left(\left(x^2 + x\right)^3 + x^4\right)+ x\right)^5.$$

Answer (score 5):

Go from outside to inside:
$$
f'(x)=5(A(x))^4 \cdot A'(x)
$$
where
$$
A(x)=((x^2 + x)^3 + x^4)+ x
$$
Now compute $A'(x)$ in a similar way.